# What is the difference between multilabel dataset and special dataset with respect to imbalance problem in datasets?

Tags: classification, data-mining, multilabel-classification

i have a multilabel data set which is imbalenced and noisy.i used BR approach to convert single lablel and perform balanceing.data is fragmented into one class now i want to merge these fragmented class to create multilabel dataset is it possible??

Comment: Welcome to DataScience SE.  What is `BR approach`?

Comment: BR(Binary relevance) is a straightforward multi-label classification approach.which decomposes the problem into a set of single-label multi-class problems. In this way, a set of multi-class classifiers are learnt and then applied to do prediction. This simple method, however, totally neglects the dependencies among multiple labels.